# Prismic Query Latest Documents without Master Ref

Tags: rest, prismic.io

How can I query the prismic REST api for the latest documents without having to specify the Master ref query?

At the moment I have to specify the `ref` key to get results:

```
https://auden-contracts-spike.prismic.io/api/v1/documents/search?ref=<MY_MASTER_REF>&access_token=<MY_ACCESS_TOKEN>&format=json
```

The API comes back with the following message when I don't provide `ref`:

```
{
    "message": "Release not provided"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it isn’t possible. 
You need to retrieve the master ref from the api endpoint before making a query.

Comment: Thank you @Nounou. Do you know the api endpoint to retrieve the master ref?

Comment: You can get the current master ref from your /api/v1 endpoint. In your case: https://auden-contracts-spike.prismic.io/api/v1